# SPARC v8: local registers usage

Tags: assembly, cpu-registers, sparc

I am using assembly program mixed with high level language.  Can I use a local registers (l0 to l7), for programming? As I have two observations.

1. Machine code generated by compiler don't have local registers.
2. Register l0 to l3 used by trap model.

Considering the above two points, can I use the local register for assembly programming?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You mean *inline* asm in GNU C inside a C function?  Use constraints like `"=r"` to let the compiler do register allocation.  But yeah if this is inside an interrupt handler or with interrupts disabled, you could manually use registers that the compiler would never choose, I guess.  I don't know enough about SPARC to write an answer.

Comment: Are you *sure* your compiler doesn't use `l0-l7`?  https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/SPARC_Assembly/SPARC_Details says `%l0..%l7` (aka `%r16–%r23`) *are* for normal usage inside functions, in the standard ABI.  I would have thought trap handling would use SPARC's register-window stuff to get access to some registers it can use.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you haven't already, have a look at this wheel diagram:
https://icps.u-strasbg.fr/people/loechner/public_html/enseignement/SPARC/sparcstack.html
It's taken from the SPARC V8 architecture manual and shows how the in, out, and local registers work.

There are two main takeaways from this diagram.

- The *in* registers of one register window overlap with the *out* registers of the next window. This can be used to pass parameters from caller functions to callees.
- The *local* registers for each window do *not* overlap with anything, so you can use them however you want without them being clobbered by other functions. Even if local registers have to be reused in hardware due to a call stack deeper than the number of physical windows, the local register values should be restored transparently via traps on window changes.

In short, the answer to your question is **yes, you can use the local registers for assembly programming.**

To address your observations:

1. Compilers will sometimes generate assembly that uses input and output registers over locals. I'm not sure why this is exactly, but I have observed the same thing on "toy" programs. If you add more variables and/or use higher optimization levels, it will likely start using locals. Remember that the i and o registers are also general purpose and can be used for more than just passing params.
2. I suspect you're mistaken here. How did you come to this conclusion?

Hope this helps. This is mostly from memory and I haven't worked on SPARC within the past year, so I welcome corrections.